# Syslog-ng not logging on debian

Tags: linux, monitoring, logging, syslog, syslog-ng

I have syslog-ng running but it does not seem to be logging to /var/log anymore.

Looking at the logs it apparently used to awhile back:

```
-rw-------  1 root  root        0 Sep  8 00:55 messages
-rw-------  1 root  root   569157 Sep  4 01:27 messages.1
-rw-------  1 root  root    55402 Sep  1 00:55 messages.2.gz
-rw-------  1 root  root    55488 Aug 25 00:55 messages.3.gz
-rw-------  1 root  root    56132 Aug 18 00:55 messages.4.gz
```

I do have it running:

```
root       419     1  0 09:01 ?        00:00:00 supervising syslog-ng
root       420   419 10 09:01 ?        00:57:32 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng -p /var/run/syslog-ng.pid --no-caps
root     30290     1  0 09:18 ?        00:00:00 supervising syslog-ng
root     30291 30290  9 09:18 ?        00:54:42 syslog-ng
```

My configurations:

```
cat  /etc/default/syslog-ng
#CONSOLE_LOG_LEVEL=1

# Command line options to syslog-ng
SYSLOGNG_OPTS="--no-caps"
```

Disk:

```
 df -h /
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs            200G  2.5G  198G   2% /
```

How do I get syslog-ng to log what my system is doing so that I can better debug the system.

Comment: 1) Is your disk full, or has it been full recently?
2) You have two `supervising syslog-ng` with attached syslog-ng processes. That's probably one too many.

Comment: Nope. Disk is very empty.

Comment: Then the second part is still relevant - get rid of both syslog-ng processes and then start it again.

Comment: I found I had to delete the file syslog-ng was writing to in order to get logging back.

Comment: what happens if you point it to a different file location in syslog-ng.conf file?